# Как установить в Ubuntu драйвер serial?

Tags: linux, драйвер

Использую beaglebone black поставил на него дистрибутив ubuntu столкнулся с тем что в нем нету всех библиотек которые мне нужны в особенно библиотек serial( 8250,omap).  Для того чтобы исправить это недоразумение пытался обновить ядро в надежде что нужные библиотеку установятся тем более что в файлах ядра они были

```
sudo apt-get install linux-header--$( uname -r)
```

ядро обновилось но библиотеки не появились. Вопрос прост как это исправить как добавить библиотеки для работы с драйвером serial(8250)?

Пример

```
#include <linux/serial_8250.h>
#include <linux/dmaengine.h>
```

он говорит что таких катологов нет

Comment: Ищите на ti.com

Comment: Они у вас есть в каталоге */lib/modules/...*, но для архитектуры **хоста**. Хотя для 8250 их обычно встраивают в ядро с целью возможности отладки. Снова же, всё можно узнать во время работы, посмотрев в каталог */sys/modules*. Вопрос в том, бывает ли Ubuntu для OMAP?

Comment: @PavelGridin, всё везде есть, тем более драйвер последовательно порта, искать стоит в других местах.

Comment: мне нужно использовать этот драйвер для передачи по RS485  вопрос как это сделать

Comment: вы установили, надеюсь, пакет `linux-headers-версия`, а не `linux-header--версия` (такого в репозиториях дистрибутива ubuntu не должно быть). по зависимости от него должен был установиться пакет `linux-headers-версия-common`, в который, в т.ч., должен входить файл `/usr/src/linux-headers-версия-common/include/linux/serial_8250.h`. так что вам просто надо правильно указать компилятору каталог для поиска заголовочных файлов.

Comment: usr/src/linux-headers-версия-common/include/linux/serial_8250.h в том то и дело что он не может подключить библиотеки что находяться внутри serial_8250.h